# Fair use for a free online school notes [UK]

Tags: united-kingdom, fair-use, england-and-wales

We are working a project for a website which will offer free notes, and we don't plan on selling them, although we may use advertising at one point to help pay for the domain etc. However, we were wondering whether any use of images would fall under "free use" in the UK, as we are not charging for access to the images or anything like that.

Regards,
hoix

Comment: Not charging makes it even worse for the copyright holder. If I sell images for $100 each and a pirate sells them for $100 as well, there will still people buying my images. If you give them away, much less likely.

Answer (score 2):

There is no “[fair use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)” in English copyright - that is a US concept. The UK has the less forgiving concept of [fair dealing](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright#fair-dealing).

Notwithstanding, what you are proposing to do with the photography is neither fair use nor fair dealing.

You need to use photographs that you own the copyright for, that you have a licence to use in that way or that are public domain. HMG provides this [summary](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/481194/c-notice-201401.pdf) of the relevant law.